# Best way to parse HTML in Qt?

Tags: c++, html, qt

How would I go about parsing all of the "a" html tags "href" properties on a page full of BAD html, in Qt?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is bad about the HTML?  Is it bad regularly, or is it complete garbage?  You can't fix what's producing the HTML?

Comment: don't use regex... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: It's a google search, Google's HTML is terrible.   Errors found while checking this document as HTML5!
Result:  50 Errors, 16 warning(s)

Comment: @JOSHUA: and those errors prevent Qt from parsing the HTML using QtWebKit?

Comment: I don't know how to use QtWebKit to do this and the only answer showing it doesn't work...  I think the page has to load or something?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would use the builtin QtWebKit. Don't know how it does in terms of performance, but I think it should catch all "bad" HTML.
Something like:

```
class MyPageLoader : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  MyPageLoader();
  void loadPage(const QUrl&);

public slots:
  void replyFinished(bool);

private:
  QWebView* m_view;
};

MyPageLoader::MyPageLoader()
{
  m_view = new QWebView();

  connect(m_view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)),
          this, SLOT(replyFinished(bool)));
}

void MyPageLoader::loadPage(const QUrl& url)
{
  m_view->load(url);
}

void MyPageLoader::replyFinished(bool ok)
{
  QWebElementCollection elements = m_view->page()->mainFrame()->findAllElements("a");

  foreach (QWebElement e, elements) {
    // Process element e
  }
}
```

To use the class

```
MyPageLoader loader;
loader.loadPage("http://www.example.com")
```

and then do whatever you like with the collection.

Comment: I cleaned this up and it didn't work... do I have to wait for the page to load or something?

Comment: @JOSHUA: I'd recommend waiting until you get the loadFinished(bool) signal, yes. (http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwebview.html#loadFinished)

Answer (score 7):

this question is already quite old. Nevertheless I hope this will help someone:

I wrote two small classes for Qt which I published under sourceforge. This will help you to access a html-file comparable you are used with XML.

Here you'll find the project:
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/sgml-for-qt/
Here you'll find a help-system in the wiki.

Drewle