# QRegExp problem

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregexp

I have written

```
QRegExp rx("<img src=\"\\S+\"\\s+width=\"(\\d+)\"\\s+height\"(\\d+)\"\\s+/>");
```

RegExp in order to match

```
 <img src="file://c/Users/Narek/Desktop/WClub.jpg" width="95" height="113.04" />
```

kind of substring in a string, in order to extract the width and height. But this does not match. Please tel me what I have done wrong.

Comment: A minor note is that it is usually considered a bad idea to process HTML using regular expressions. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179477/best-way-to-parse-html-in-qt on how to parse HTML in Qt.

Comment: This link is for parsing only, but I parse in order to edit, so I dont find convenient the method proposed in the question whose link is written above. May be there is a better aproach then the QRegExp but not this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last `\d` doesn't take account of the dot inside the number, and you are missing '=' after 'height'.

Answer (score 4):

`\d` does not match the period in your height.

A regular expression that would work would be something like:

```
<img src=\"[^"]*\"\s+width=\"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\"\s+height=\"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\"\s+/>
```

Also, the obligatory comment that it is a [bad idea to parse HTML using Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Yes, right, but even <img src="file://c/Users/Narek/Desktop/WClub.jpg" width="95" height="113" />  can not be matched :(

Comment: @Joel: Thanks, I also forgot the capture groups. That's why one should use a HTML parser, huh? :)

Comment: @Narek: The decimal and digits after are optional. That is what the non-capturing group `(?:\.\d+)?` does.

Comment: This is the best answer so far. An alternative to `\"[^"]*\"` is a call to `setMinimal(true)` to make quantifiers non-greedy.

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
QRexExp rx("<img src=[^<]+/\> ");
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Sorry, I had trouble displaying the <img> node :)