# how can I autodetect the rss url (if available) out of any given website url for blackberry cascades?

Tags: rss, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

SO i have a webview displaying user defined websites. I want to autodetect if that url contains any rss feed and post it in a Label/textarea.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward way is to parse the HTML into a DOM document, then traverse the document looking for nodes that define RSS links. You may try using [QXmlSimpleReader](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/qxmlsimplereader.html) but this can be frustrating because most HTML is not well formed XML so you will have to handle exceptions.

In an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179477/best-way-to-parse-html-in-qt), the following [SourceForge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sgml-for-qt/) was recommended. This might be worth a look.